# Laravel role management in view

Tags: php, laravel, controller, filtering, roles

I'm making a Laravel application that includes a role management system, using entrust and confide.

So when a route is browsed (eg /questions), the blade view file that should be displayed depends on the user type. I solved this problem by making a switch in every controller function

```
public function getQuestions(){
    $questions = Question::all();

    switch(Auth::User()->getRoleName()){
        case 'Moderator':
        return View::make('questions.moderator.index',array('questions'=>$questions));
        break;

        case 'Teacher':
        return View::make('questions.teacher.index',array('questions'=>$questions));
        break;

        case 'Student':
        return View::make('questions.student.index',array('questions'=>$questions));
        break;

        default:
        return App:abort(404);

    }


}
```

But I guess this isn't the best way to solve this problem. I'm actually looking for a kind of filtering in the controller.

So my question is: what would be the best way to handle this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you looking for but you can reduce the code using this:

```
public function getQuestions(){
    try {
        $role = strtolower(Auth::User()->getRoleName());
        $questions = Question::all();
        return View::make("questions.{$role}.index", compact('questions'));
    } catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        // create a view "app/views/roleNotFound.blade.php"
        return Response::view('errors.roleNotFound', array(), 404);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may also register an exception (InvalidArgumentException) handler in `global.php` file (instead of `try/catch`):

```
App::error(function(InvalidArgumentException $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    return Response::view('errors.roleNotFound', array(), $code);
});
```

You may also use a filter:

```
Route::filter('role', function($route, $request){

    // depending on role, you may redirect to a
    // different route, for example; if not admin
    // then redirect to home page or whatever
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $role = strtolower(Auth::User()->getRoleName());
        if($role != 'admin') return Redirect::to('/');
    }
    else {
        // return to som url if not login
        // or whatever you want
    }
});

Route::get('/questions', array('before' => 'role:', 'uses' => 'Question@getQuestions'));
```